# magento custom admin module edit data field not retrieve data

Tags: php, magento

I am creating custom admin module where grid, edit, new, delete work as same as product grid. Everything working fine but when i click on grid row to edit item it redirects correctly but the text field does't contains data. currently i am having one field called name my editAction as follows:

```
public function editAction()
    {
     $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', null);
        $model = Mage::getModel('fondation/fondation');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load((int) $id);
            if ($model->getId()) {
                $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
                if ($data) {
                    $model->setData($data)->setId($id);
                }
            } else {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('fondation')->__('Example does not exist'));              $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
        }
        Mage::register('fondation_data', $model);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
        $this->renderLayout();
}
```

form Class

```
class Npm_Fondation_Block_Adminhtml_Fondation_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('fondation_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('fondation')->__('Item information')));
        $fieldset->addField('Name', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('fondation')->__('Name'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'name',
        ));
        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFondationData()) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFondationData());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFondationData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('fondation_data')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('fondation_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your form class ?

Comment: Hi, I have added the form class